# Jquery Datatable sum conditional footer callback not displaying correct result

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to calculate sum of columns from footer callback but . It is not giving me the correct result . Total sum for USE should be 12 but it is displaying 24. As well as for RAHUL also It is displaying wrong result. If the value is repeated like 6 is twice for USE and 6 is also present in the Card and Other . In this case it is calculating in the latest came result .

[JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/552y9j90/154/)

```js
$("#table1").DataTable({
  "paging": false,
  "searching": false,
  "info": false,
  "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {

    var columns = [2, 3];
    //console.log(data);
    var api = this.api();

    // Get sumCondition and put in array     

    _.each(columns, function(idx) {

      var total = api
        .column(idx)
        .data()
        .reduce(function(a, b) {
          // Find index of current value for accessing sumCondition value in same row
          var cur_index = api.column(idx).data().indexOf(b);
          if (api.column(1).data()[cur_index] === "Use") {
            return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
          } else {
            return parseInt(a);
          }
        }, 0)

      //
      var rahulTotal = api
        .column(idx)
        .data()
        .reduce(function(a, b) {
          // Find index of current value for accessing sumCondition value in same row
          var cur_index = api.column(idx).data().indexOf(b);
          if (api.column(1).data()[cur_index] === "Rahul") {
            return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
          } else {
            return parseInt(a);
          }
        }, 0)
      $('tr:eq(0) th:eq(' + idx + ')', api.table().footer()).html(total);
    })

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fruit</th>
      <th>sumCondition</th>
      <th># Eaten</th>
      <th># Remaining</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th align="center">Count</th>
      <th align="left"></th>
      <th align="left"></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td>Use</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td>Card</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td>Other</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td>Rahul</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mango</td>
      <td>Use</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bananas</td>
      <td>Rahul</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about here. What is your expected result?

Comment: If sumCondition == 'Use' . Total is displaying 24 but in case of sumCondition == 'Use'  total should come only 12. I want to get the total of this column only . I do not want to get total of all the values . I am using cur_index for that purpose only.

If u will open the link https://jsfiddle.net/552y9j90/154/
You will get to know the result .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reason

The problem is due to this line

```
var cur_index = api.column(idx).data().indexOf(b);
```

As state in [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element
>   can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

Hence when passing **b=6** will always return the first row

Apple | Use | 6 | 5

Hence the sum will be 24.

### Solution

The following snippet reduce the whole data, instead of one column, so that there is no need to get the current row index.

```js
$("#table1").DataTable({
  "paging": false,
  "searching": false,
  "info": false,
  "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {

    var columns = [2, 3];
    //console.log(data);
    var api = this.api();

    // Get sumCondition and put in array     

    _.each(columns, function(idx) {

      var total = total = api.data().reduce(function(a, b) {
        var prev = 0;
        var next = 0;
        if (Array.isArray(a)) {
          if (a[1] === "Use") {
            prev = parseInt(a[idx]);
          }

        } else {
          prev  = a;
        }
        if (b[1] === "Use") {
            next = parseInt(b[idx]);
        }
        return prev + next;
      },0);

      $('tr:eq(0) th:eq(' + idx + ')', api.table().footer()).html(total);
    })

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fruit</th>
      <th>sumCondition</th>
      <th># Eaten</th>
      <th># Remaining</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th align="center">Count</th>
      <th align="left"></th>
      <th align="left"></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td>Use</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td>Card</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td>Other</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td>Rahul</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mango</td>
      <td>Use</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bananas</td>
      <td>Rahul</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I still did not understand the question clearly. But from what i get, i think this is what you are looking for

```
$("#table1").DataTable({
  "paging": false,
  "searching": false,
  "info": false,    
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
      var columns = [2, 3];
      //console.log(data);
      var api = this.api();
      // Get sumCondition and put in array     

      _.each(columns, function(idx) {
                    var total = 0;
                    _.each(api.column(idx).data(), function(i, v) {
            if(api.column(1).data()[v] === "Use") {
                total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(i);
            }
          });

                $('tr:eq(0) th:eq('+idx+')', api.table().footer()).html(total);

      })

  }
});
```