# Datatables footerCallback, exclude rows and sum it with JSON data

Tags: html, jquery, json, datatables

This question is based on [footerCallback with duplicate cell numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72447620/footercallback-with-duplicate-cell-numbers)

I implement the solution from @andrewJames (thanks).

I'm trying to sum last column of the table exept the salary of `System Architect` and `Senior Javascript Developer`

But now there is a problem when I use JSON data. The `sum` is always `0`... instead of $9

HTML:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="large-12 columns">


  <table id="example" class="display nowrap table1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Seq.</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Seq.</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>

  </div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var salaryTable = {
    "data": [
        {
            "Seq": "1",
            "Name": "Tiger Nixon",
            "Position": "System Architect",
            "Salary": "$1"
        },
        {
            "Seq": "1",
            "Name": "Garrett Winters",
            "Position": "Accountant",
            "Salary": "$1"
        },
        {
            "Seq": "3",
            "Name": "Ashton Cox",
            "Position": "Junior Technical Author",
            "Salary": "$3"
        },
        {
            "Seq": "4",
            "Name": "Cedric Kelly",
            "Position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
            "Salary": "$4"
        },
        {
            "Seq": "5",
            "Name": "Airi Satou",
            "Position": "Accountant",
            "Salary": "$5"
        }
    ]
}; 
 
 
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        rowReorder: {
        selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
      },
      data: salaryTable.data,
            columns: [
            { data: "Seq" },
            { data: "Name" },
            { data: "Position" },
            { data: "Salary" }
        ],
      responsive: true,
      scrollX: true,
      scrollY: "80vh",
        scrollCollapse: true,
            paging: true,
      lengthChange: false,
      lengthMenu: [ [10, 25, -1], [10, 25, "All"] ],
      "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
      "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;
 
            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };
 
            filteredTotal = api.rows().data().reduce(function (a, b) {
              // filterMe will be true or false:
              filterMe = b[2] === "System Architect" || b[2] === "Senior Javascript Developer";

              // if filterMe is true then use 0, otherwise use the actual amount from b[3]:
              salary = filterMe ? 0 : intVal(b[3]);

              return a + salary;
            }, 0 );
 
            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 3, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(
                '$'+filteredTotal+'/ all $'+pageTotal
            );
        },
        buttons: ['pdf', 'print']
    } );
 
    table.buttons().container()
        .appendTo( '#example_wrapper .small-6.columns:eq(0)' );
} );
   $(document).foundation();
```

Fiddle with the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/87360vyx/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between this Ajax approach and your [previous HTML approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72447620/12567365) is this:

When DataTables pulls its data directly from an HTML table, a row of data is handled as a JavaScript array of values:

```js
[ '1', 'Tiger Nixon', 'System Architect', ... ]
```

But with the JSON you are using in this question, the equivalent row of data is stored in DataTables as a JavaScript object:

```
{ Seq: "1", Name: "Tiger Nixon", Position: "System Architect", ... }
```

Therefore you cannot access row values using code like `b[2]`. Instead you have to use `b.Position`. And instead of `b[3]` you have to use `b.Salary`.

---

You can see the difference for yourself by adding a `console.log( b );` statement to each of the different versions of the code, inside the `rows().data().reduce(...)` code. That will show you exactly how DataTables is handling its row data, internally.

You can also an official example here: [Ajax data source (objects)](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help and time to explain me... :)